# Django input request.META into requests headers?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a Django application in which I want to get a page from my own website, and mimic a client side request by passing the request's headers and cookies.

**middleware.py**

```
r = requests.get('https://google.com', None, headers=request.META, cookies=request.COOKIES)
```

However, I noticed that in Django the `request.META` is capitalized and uses underscores instead of hyphens. While `request.COOKIES` returns empty, which leads me to believe they don't show up in middleware?

Am I missing something, this seems to be quite a downer since requests is such a popular library and Django is such a popular framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have set the cookie properly?  I have tested this with a small piece of custom middleware and `request.COOKIES` had the cookie present.  Here was my view:

```
def test(request):
    response = HttpResponse('test')
    response.set_cookie('foo', 'bar')
    return response
```

Then, after setting a breakpoint with `ipdb` in my custom middleware:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

I could see the set cookie just fine:

```
ipdb> request.COOKIES
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Hm I will test again. However, the main question was passing request.META into the headers param :P

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what your question is.  Are you just looking for confirmation that Django modifies the header keys in request.META?  According to the docs, you are right: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: I think my question is: Is there some way I can enter the META dictionary into requests' header param?

Comment: @John It seems the best you can do is write something that will reverse their encoding strategy.  For instance, by stripping `HTTP_` from the beginning, converting the underscores to hyphens, and change the capitalization to title-case.  In this case, `HTTP_FOO_BAR` would become `Foo-Bar`.  You should verify that every header you want is going through, since from the docs it looks like `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE` aren't translated in the same way.